# How to enable Gallium driver and remove radeon xorg driver, vesa,etc

Tags: drivers, ati, video, radeon

How to remove radeon xorg driver, vesa etc. and enable de default Gallium driver?

Answer (score 1):

To enable Gallium add `Option "ForceGallium" "true"` in **/etc/X11/xorg.conf**

You can remove what you want from synaptic if you have else you can use the commands:

For Vesa: `sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-glint`

For other ATI drivers: `sudo apt-get remove xorg-driver-fglrx"`

Comment: how do i deactivate gallium and successfully install catalyst?